# Replace all text between braces { } in Java with regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a long string with numerous occurences of text between { } that I would like to remove however when I do this:

```
data = data.replaceAll("{(.*?)}", "");
```

i get an error, so what am I doing wrong / how should I go about doing this?

Comment: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html
this is a good place to test your regexs before using them

Answer (score 15):

This will replace all text between curly brackets and leave the brackets
This is done using positive look ahead and positive look behind

```
data = data.replaceAll("(?<=\\{).*?(?=\\})", "");
```

"if (true) { calc(); }" becomes "if (true) {}"

This will replace all text between curly brackets and remove the brackets

```
data = data.replaceAll("\\{.*?\\}", "");
```

"if (true) { calc(); }" becomes "if (true)"

This will replace all text between curly brackets, including new lines.

```
data = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\{).*?(?=\\})", Pattern.DOTALL).matcher(data).replaceAll("");
```

"if (true) { \n\t\tcalc();\n }" becomes "if (true) {}"

Answer (score 5):

You need to escape the opening brace as it denotes the start of the quantifier - `{n}` in regex. And you don't really need that capture groups, so remove it.

```
data = data.replaceAll("\\{.*?}", "");
```

Comment: Tried this, and there is no error but the text between { } is not being removed.

Comment: @Jister13. Do you have nested braces?

Comment: @Jister13. For that string, it should certainly work. Is there any newline character in between?

Comment: Nope, it just leaves everything there.

Comment: @Jister13. As far as your string is like you have shown, this would work. If you have any newline characters before `{` and after it. That means, if your code is indented, then that would not work. Further, for any complex string, it can go uglier. You would be better off writing your own parser.

Answer (score 1):

In general, this is a job that's not suited for regex to begin with. Usually if "{ text }" is possible then so is: "{ { text1 } { text2 } }" which cannot be parsed properly with regex.

This is the same reason why XML/HTML parsers do not use regex

Comment: How would I go about this then?  Without using regex?

Comment: Well it depends on EXACTLY what you want. If you want to take in text where there are no nested braces, then this works fine. Or if you only want to remove the outermost braces, (that is { { text1 } { text2 } } will become "") then it works as well. But as soon as you want to parse bigger text and you want to do some transformation on every pair of braces when they're nested it won't work. Doing the parsing manually with loops, keeping track of open and closed braces with a counter would be suitable in that case

Comment: I just want to remove all text between any braces in the string

Comment: @Jister13 then the regex in rohain's answer should do. Perhaps change the `.*?` to `.*` to make it more greedy, and consume everything, not just up to the first closing brace.

Comment: No, because that will turn "a { b } c { d } e" into "a  e". If there were no nesting, you could use "\\{[^}]*}", but this really needs a parser.

Answer (score 1):

try this, may this will help you.

```
String refinedData = new String(data);
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{[^\\}]*\\}");
Matcher m = p.matcher(data);
while(m.find()){
    String d = data.substring(m.start(), m.end());
    refinedData = refinedData.replace(d, "");
}
```

Comment: No, don't do that.  If the regex matches what it's supposed to, it will work in the OP's code (i.e. `data = data.replaceAll("\\{[^\\}]*\\}", "");`).  It never makes sense to do a `replace()` inside a `while (matcher.find())` loop.

Comment: @AlanMoore Except when you want to add some condition based on the matched value. (e.g. replacing hex values by characters, `(0x20)` by a space).

Answer (score 0):

When you need to match a substring from a *single character* up to another *single* character, the best regex solution is to use the delimiters and insert in-between them a [**negated character class**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) that matches any character but the delimiter characters.

So, the **basic pseudo pattern** is

```
a  [^ ab  ]*  b
```

where:

- `a` - a starting delimiter
- `[^ab]*` - zero or more characters other than `a` and `b`
- `b` - a trailing delimiter.

So, **to replace all text between `{` and `}` (between braces)**, use

```
String data = "text 1 {\ntext 2\ntext 3\n}";
System.out.println(data.replaceAll("\\{[^{}]*}", ""));
// => text 1
```

See the [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/KRUhD8)

Note that in Java regex, `{` and `}` do not have to be escaped inside the character class, and `}` does not have to be escaped even  outside of it. Only `{` *outside of a character class* must be escaped (or put into a character class) so as not to form a limiting quantifier construct.